# Quando é recomendado o uso de chave primária composta?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, chave-primária, chave-composta

> Uma chave **simples** é associada a um único valor, ou campo, do registro. Uma chave **composta** corresponde à combinação de duas ou mais chaves, e pode ser necessária para eliminar a ambiguidade, formando um identificador único. ([Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_%28computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29))

Vamos supor, apenas como exemplo, que eu vá implementar um *blog* com o uso de **chave primária simples**. Os registros ficariam assim:

```
Tabela posts:
| id |     post     |
-------------------
|  1 | "Um post"    |
|  2 | "Outro post" |

Tabela comentarios:
| id | post_id |    comentario    |
---------------------------------
|  1 |       1 | "Meu comentário" |
|  2 |       1 | "Meu comentário" |
|  3 |       1 | "Meu comentário" |
|  4 |       2 | "Meu comentário" |
|  5 |       2 | "Meu comentário" |
|  6 |       2 | "Meu comentário" |
```

Ou seja: os comentários teriam chaves primárias (coluna `id`) únicas em relação a todos os comentários, mesmo de outros *posts*.

Se eu usasse **chave primária composta** os comentários teriam `id`'s únicos apenas com relação ao seu *post* (coluna `post_id`):

```
Tabela comentarios:
| post_id | id |    comentario    |
---------------------------------
|       1 |  1 | "Meu comentário" |
|       1 |  2 | "Meu comentário" |
|       1 |  3 | "Meu comentário" |
|       2 |  1 | "Meu comentário" |
|       2 |  2 | "Meu comentário" |
|       2 |  3 | "Meu comentário" |
```

O mesmo princípio vale para outras situações, como uma nota fiscal e seus itens, por exemplo.

Em que situações é recomendado o uso da chave primária composta? E quando é melhor usar chave primária simples?

Comment: Qual é a diferença da tabela `comentários` do primeiro e dos segundo exemplo? Do jeito que está postado, elas são idênticas, só se falta alguma coisa. A única diferença é que no segundo exemplo você não mostra a tabela de `posts`. Da maneira que está eu diria que a resposta é use qualquer uma.

Comment: @bigown Preste atenção nos id's dos comentários. No segundo exemplo eles só não se repetem em relação à coluna `post_id`. No primeiro exemplo eles não se repetem eu relação a nenhum outro comentário, mesmo os de outros posts.

Comment: Entendi, sua pergunta é sobre usar um ID geral ou um ID que na verdade é um item específico do post.

Comment: ID vs Chave composta: como? quando? porque?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No seu caso acredito que seu campo `comentário` deve ter seu próprio `id` e deve ter o o `post_id` sendo usado como chave estrangeira, assim como no caso das notas fiscais, já que nesses casos você está falando de um relacionamento 1xN (um comentário pertence a um, e apenas um post, já o post possui 0 ou muitos comentários).

O uso de chave primária composta *pode* ser feito quando você possui dois campos que juntos sempre serão únicos para aquela tabela, por exemplo:

Em um determinado aeroporto saem voos todos os dias, o número dos voos é sempre o mesmo para um determinado horário e um determinado destino, por exemplo, o voo com destino a Guarulhos no horário das 20:00 é de numero 1212. Independente do dia, o voo 1212 sempre será com o destino a Guarulhos e sempre no horário das 20:00, logo você não pode usar `voo` como chave primária, nem mesmo `data`, pois em um mesmo dia saem inúmeros voos. Nesse caso você poderia usar os campos `voo` e `data` como chaves primárias, pois eles juntos são únicos, já que nunca terá o mesmo voo duas vezes em um mesmo dia.

```
| voo  |    data    | outros campos...
--------------------------------------
| 1212 | 14/05/2014 |
| 1234 | 14/05/2014 | 
| 2345 | 14/05/2014 | 
| 1212 | 15/05/2014 |
| 1234 | 15/05/2014 | 
| 2345 | 15/05/2014 |
```

Você também poderia atribuir um id para cada registro e usar uma única chave primária, entretanto isso depende da sua modelagem.

Transcrevendo tudo que foi dito nos comentários:
Me arrisco a dizer que para todos os casos que a situação se assemelhe com a tabela fictícia de voos, você poderá **optar** tanto por usar duas colunas como chave primária composta ou por criar um id e ter uma chave primária simples.

Diferenças:

- Optando por usar duas colunas como chave primária você economiza um campo na sua tabela, e também você já está adicionando uma *constraint* a sua tabela garantindo a consistência dos dados. A desvantagem nesse caso é ter que usar dois campos em toda operação que você fizer que necessita pegar um único registro, como select, update, delete, etc. Outra desvantagem é que para cada tabela relacional que você fizer, terá um campo a mais, logo a primeira vantagem que eu citei acaba não compensando essa desvantagem, já que uma tabela relacional costuma ter muito mais registros do que as tabelas que ela relaciona.
- Optando por usar o id, fica mais fácil fazer os relacionamentos com outras tabelas, pois você usará apenas um campo sempre.  A desvantagem é que você terá um campo a mais em sua tabela. Outro ponto que não é desvantagem nem vantagem é que você terá que colocar os *constraints* a parte, indicando quais campos são únicos, vale lembrar que é possível dizer que dois campos juntos são únicos, similar a uma chave primária composta.

Na maioria dos casos, as vantagens e desvantagens de cada são quase desconsideráveis, portanto escolha a opção que você ficar mais a vontade.

Só consegui imaginar um caso em que uma opção seria melhor do que a outra, seria se seu modelo tiver muitos relacionamentos NxN, pois a quantidade de campos aumentaria de uma forma considerável, mais ainda se ao invés de dois campos você tiver inúmeros campos como chave primária, para cada tabela você possuirá uma quantidade muito superior de campos e dados.

Comment: e se programaticamente pegasses nessas 2 chaves e as convertesses num id único coposto tipo: 112214052014, não seria melhor em termos de pesquisa?

Comment: O resumo de tudo isto é que chave primária, por default deve ser simples, deve ser um ID geral para a tabela (há casos que deveria ser universal para a base toda ou até algo único mesmo além da base), uma chave composta só deveria ser usada se houver necessidade real justificada para isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. em termos de eficiência: não faço ideia; em termos de facilidade de operação: dúvido, pois você estaria simplesmente duplicando os dados e teria que fazer uma conta a mais para buscar o id. Na verdade a ideia de manter esses campos como chave primária ao invés de fazer um id sequencial é a de por uma _constraint_ para validação dos dados, pois assim garantiria que não haverá inconsistência dos dados.

Comment: @bigown então neste caso acima porias um id em vez de chave voo, data?

Comment: Continuo na mesma, um diz para fazer com id o outro com o par de chaves primarias, em que ficamos? :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Sempre é complicado especular sem casos reais específicos, um modelo não pode ser olhado por uma ou duas tabelas, sem ver o contexto geral, mas arriscando assim mesmo, eu diria que sim. Eu **prefiro** sempre um ID. Inclusive facilita mudanças futuras de modelo. Usar a chave composta pode até ser uma forma de otimização, seria algo semelhante a desnormalizar. Talvez eu deva dar minha resposta :) Mas não sei se justifica. Se eu lembrar como fundamentar, eu posto.

Comment: @JorgeB. depende da sua necessidade, os dois jeitos são tecnicamente corretos, ou seja, não terá inconsistência dos dados. Eu particularmente sempre opto por colocar ids sequenciais, nunca houve o caso de eu **precisar** de chaves primárias compostas. Se você quiser garantir a consistência no caso da tabela dos voos pode simplesmente colocar os dois campos como `unique`, entretanto um `unique` composto, e deixar o id sequencial ser a chave primária.

Comment: Falo isso porque eu tenho um caso que ia perguntar ontem, mas acabei por não ter tempo, e encaixa-se bem aqui. Eu tenho um caso em que tenho 4 chaves compostas para identificar uma linha da tabela. E pensei, será que deveria ter ou usar um ID? Acho que seria interessante esclarecer isso nas respostas a esta pergunta.
ID vs Chave composta como? quando? porque?

Comment: @Math mas quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar id?

Comment: @JorgeB. diria eu que a vantagem de não usar o id é que você teria um campo a menos na sua tabela, entretanto não sei até onde isso é vantagem. A vantagem de usar id é que é mais fácil quando você vai relacionar com outra tabela, pois uma vez que você tem apenas um campo como chave primária você evitará fazer `AND`s em consultas e outras operações. Resumindo: a diferença é mínima, ou eu que não sei outras (des)vantagens, rs.. para mim são essas. Ou seja, não sei de casos que você **precise** fazer de um jeito ou de outro, vai do gosto do cliente.

Comment: Chave composta tem seus usos e às vezes é melhor do que criar um (terceiro) Id. Um exemplo comum são tabelas relacionais onde temos uma tabela tAxB relacionando tabelas tA e tB e temos apenas um A para cada B e os ids de A e B são únicos

Comment: @jean qual é o sentido em criar uma tabela relacional para uma relação de 1xN? Tabelas relacionais são de serventia apenas em relacionamentos NxN.

Comment: @Math Acho que ele estava falando justamente de uma relação muitos-para-muitos.

Comment: @Andrey `temos apenas um A para cada B` me deu a entender que é 1xN

Comment: @jean Não vi muita vantagem entre fazer oque tu falou e criar um `id` para esta tabela e uma *constraint* que garante a unicidade da(s) referência(s).

Comment: @Math Tu está certo, agora eu entendi oque ele disse =)

Comment: @Math Falo de um exemplo genérico NxM e não do exemplo postado pelo OP que é 1 para N e que fica melhor usando um id simples único por comentário

Answer (score 4):

Respondendo a dúvida inicial em usar ou não usar PK composta.
Por experiência eu aprendi levando porrada que não é bom utilizar chave composta.

Podemos citar como exemplo para utilizar PK única:

- Banco de dados que tenham campos identity (auto sequencial) é mais fácil de utulizar
- Fazer update / delete no where é mais fácil e rápido (imagina você ter que usar 10 campos no where
- Mais fácil visualizar em outras tabelas
- inner join e left join são mais fácil e rápido de fazer

O único motivo para uma chave composta seria numa tabela N:N, porém neste casos, prefiro fazer uma PK única, e o constrain para validar os outros campos.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: "Fazer update / delete no where é mais fácil e rápido (imagina você ter que usar 10 campos no where" Isto se já tiveres o Id anteriormente, senão é igual.

Answer (score 4):

Chave composta deve ser usada se e somente se você quiser garantir a integridade referencial no seu banco de dados de que nunca existirá uma combinação igual destas chaves para um registro na mesma tabela.

Eu confesso que posso garantir essa integridande utilizando indices compostos únicos e nunca precisei recorrer às PK compostas. Pois no fim isso adiciona complexidade na hora de consultar e um manipular um registro.

Outro ponto que pode ser levado em conta aqui é a indexação mais rápida se voce quiser por exemplo economizar joins utilizando uma consulta em uma das chaves ou indices compostos mas isso poderia ser feito com FKs assim como PKs compostas.

Sinceramente, eu recomendo **nunca utilizar**.