# Chave primária composta ou chave primária mais índice único?

Tags: sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório no meu sistema para controlar a produtividade das equipes, a tabela de equipes possui as seguintes informações:

```
(tblequipe)
| id (pk) | nome | meta |
|    1    | EQ01 |  5   |
|    2    | EQ02 |  7   |
|    3    | EQ03 |  6   |
```

Um problema que encontrei foi ao exibir a produtividade das equipes quando não existiam dados, por exemplo, como vou considerar a produtividade da equipe no dia 01/01 se não existe nenhum lançamento (esse lançamento fica em uma tabela que contém os dados brutos, ou seja, vários registros que serão somados dando a quantidade total executada em um certo dia) nessa data? Então pensei em criar essas duas tabelas:

```
(tblmapa)
| data  | id_equipe | meta |
| 01/01 |     1     |   5  |
| 02/01 |     1     |   5  |
    .         .         .
    .         .         .
    .         .         .
| 31/01 |     1     |   5  |

---------------------------------

(tblprodutividade)
| data  | id_equipe | executado |
| 01/01 |     1     |     9     |
| 05/01 |     1     |     3     |
| 06/01 |     1     |     5     |
```

Feito isso conseguiria recuperar os dados com esse select:

```
SELECT
    m.data,
    m.id_equipe,
    m.meta,
    isnull(p.executado, 0) executado
FROM
    tblmapa m
    left join tblprodutividade p on (p.data = m.data and p.id_equipe = m.id_equipe)
```

A minha duvida é com relação a `tblmapa` e a `tblprodutividade`, gostaria de saber se é mais indicado criar uma coluna *id* em cada uma delas como *identity primary key* e definir as colunas `data` e `id_equipe` como *unique* ou talvez somente criar as colunas `data` e `id_equipe` como *primary key* composta.

**Adicional**
Gostaria de uma resposta que leva em consideração o desempenho e o espaço para armazenamento da *primari key* + *unique* ou *primary key* composta, sendo que as colunas são do tipo *date* e *int* respectivamente.

**Pergunta relacionada**
[Quando é recomendado o uso de chave primária composta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15883/quando-%C3%A9-recomendado-o-uso-de-chave-prim%C3%A1ria-composta)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tabelas para registros que possuem identidade sempre terão uma chave primária natural.

Você está tentando decidir entre usar esta chave primária natural como chave primária física da tabela ou usar uma *[surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)* como chave primária física e garantir a integridade da chave primária natural através de um índice único.

As duas abordagens são válidas mas **o fator de decisão raramente (acho que nunca) é espaço de armazenamento ou desempenho**.

## Preocupação com desempenho não é importante porque:

Uma pesquisa pela primary key [clusterizada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx) pode melhorar a performance.

Mas você pode eleger tanto a primary key quanto qualquer outro índice como **clustered** (apenas um deles, é lógico, mas pode ser qualquer um deles).

Então se você for usar surrage key (incluir a coluna ID), basta criar esta primary key não clusterizada, e tornar clusterizado o índice único que representa a chave primária natural.

Então, qualquer uma das duas opções terá a mesma performance bastando que você crie os índices adequadamente.

## Preocupação com espaço não é importante porque:

Se você usar surrogate key, de fato você consumirá mais espaço pois além do índice criado pelo banco para esta primary key física você ainda terá que criar mais um índice para a primary key natural. Mas o espaço ocupado por um índice a mais não deve ser sua primeira preocupação.

A menos que você pretenda atingir muitos milhões ou bilhões de registros nos próximos anos, performance e espaço é a última preocupação. Mesmo que você vá pagar por GB de armazenamento (uma hospedagem na nuvem, por exemplo), o espaço ocupado pelo índice não será tão relevante quanto outros fatores do banco de dados.

## Conclusão

**O fator de decisão é o design do aplicativo que vai consumir este banco de dados**. Utilizar surrogate key simplifica o uso de [ORMs](http://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/) e diminui a necessidade de refactoring complexo do banco de dados no caso de a chave primária natural mudar (a chave primária natural pode mudar devido a novos requisitos de negócio).

Dado os requisitos que você expôs, não inclua a coluna ID pois você não a está utilizando para nada nem sofre dos problemas que eu descrevi (ORM e refactoring).