# Duvida sobre IndexedDB

Tags: banco-de-dados, indexeddb

Estou precisando de fazer uma tabela muitos para muitos no IndexedDB, onde tenho Pessoas Turmas e Turma_Pessoas, a pessoa pode participar de varias turmas, e varias turmas podem ter vários alunos, ai criei esta tabela turma pessoa, onde coloco código da pessoas, código da turma, uma flag para identificar quem é a pessoa naquela turma. Segue o código da minha tabela.

```
    var pessoa turma = db.createObjectStore("tbl_PESSOA_TURMA", {keyPath: "COD_IDENT_TURMA"});

pessoa_turma .createIndex("COD_IDENT_PESSO", "COD_IDENT_PESSO", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma .createIndex("COD_IDENT_CELUL", "COD_IDENT_TURMA", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma .createIndex("FLG_IDENT_PESSO", "FLG_IDENT_PESSO", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma .createIndex("COD_IDULT_ATUAL", "COD_IDULT_ATUAL", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma .createIndex("DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", "DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", {unique: false});
```

Com este código estou conseguindo salvar apenas alguma parte da turma, porque o código da turma esta sofrendo um "group by", por exemplo tenho 16 pessoas, e ele aparece apenas 3 turmas, porque estas 16 pessoas estão em 3 turmas diferentes.

> Como devo fazer para aceitar o cadastro de mais de um código igual ? Preciso que o código da turma fique como uma chave primaria, pois na pesquisa por turma preciso que ele me retorne todos os códigos de pessoas que tem o código da turma 'X'.

Comment: Se essa tabela é a de `turma_pessoas`, a PK não pode ser o código da turma apenas. Você mesmo disse que essa tabela é de um relacionamento N-M, ou seja, a PK deveria ser COD_IDENT_TURMA  e COD_IDENT_PESSO.

Comment: Porem o IndexedDB não permite fazer isto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso, o problema é que com a PK é o campo COD_IDENT_TURMA, ele não aceita dois registros com a mesma chave.

Uma alternativa, seria fazer com que a tabela tivesse a PK composta (COD_IDENT_TURMA e COD_IDENT_PESSO). 
Mas no seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86374/duvida-sobre-indexeddb#comment173963_86374) você diz que o `IndexedDB` não suporta isso.

Então, uma possível solução para que você possa armazenar as informações da forma como quer, é criar uma nova coluna (COD_PESSOA_TURMA) para que seja sua PK.

```
|tbl_PESSOA_TURMA|
+----------------+
|COD_PESSOA_TURMA| (PK)
|COD_IDENT_TURMA |
|COD_IDENT_PESSOA|
```

Dessa forma, você conseguirá inserir registros de vários alunos de várias turmas sem que haja violação de PK, uma vez que ela será um ID sequencial.

---

[Pergunta relacionada no SO Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408241/indexeddb-and-many-to-many-relationships)

[Quando é recomendado o uso de chave primária composta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15883)

Comment: Não fiz desta forma, e conseguir. Mas esta forma também irá funcionar.

Comment: Então, poste a forma que você fez. Pode ser que futuramente ela irá ajudar mais pessoas que venham a ter a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

O js ficou desta forma:

```
    bd =    db.transaction("tbl_PESSOA_CELULA").objectStore("tbl_PESSOA_CELULA"),
    singleKeyRange = IDBKeyRange.only(w_codigo_turma);

index = bd.index("COD_IDENT_TURMA");
index.openCursor(singleKeyRange).onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {           
       console.log(cursor.value.COD_IDENT_PESSO);
       cursor.continue();
    }
```

E o banco de dados estruturei assim:

```
var pessoa_turma= db.createObjectStore("tbl_PESSOA_TURMA", { autoIncrement : true });

pessoa_turma.createIndex("COD_IDENT_PESSO", "COD_IDENT_PESSO", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma.createIndex("COD_IDENT_CELUL", "COD_IDENT_TURMA", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma.createIndex("FLG_IDENT_PESSO", "FLG_IDENT_PESSO", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma.createIndex("COD_IDULT_ATUAL", "COD_IDULT_ATUAL", {unique: false});
pessoa_turma.createIndex("DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", "DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", {unique: false});
```

No meu banco de dados estruturei de forma a criar um key, autoincrement, isto gera código em sequencia para cada registro da tabela pessoa turma, acima para chegar a resposta do código dos alunos de determinada turma, eu criei um index, para informar qual campo eu quero da tabela, criei um IDBKeyRange que me possibilita criar algo para ser comparado, é o sinônimo de `where` no MYSql, e por ultimo criei um cursor, a função dele é percorrer todo o resultado obtido na query especificada.