# Usar AND dentro de um INNER JOIN pode?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, join

Gostaria de saber se é possível usar `AND` dentro de um `INNER JOIN`, exemplo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab1
 INNER JOIN tab2
    ON tab2.id2 = tab1.id1
   AND tab2.camp1 = 'valor'
 INNER JOIN tab3
    ON tab3.id3 = tab2.id2;
```

Dei um exemplo bem bobo, mas a questão é se tem alguma forma de usar o `AND` depois do `ON` e antes de um outro `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim é possível ter uma ou mais clásulas `JOIN` composta com operadores como `AND`, `OR` `<>` etc. O equi join é mais comum mesmo.

Basicamente o join composto já descarta os registros que não atendem o critério na junção. Caso tenha um join 'simples' e mais a frente um `WHERE` significa que o descarte será na restrição, ou seja primeiro feita é a junção e depois o descarte.

O 'descarte' feito no `JOIN` (junção)

```
SELECT * FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND td2.data = '2017-02-10'
```

O 'descarte' feito no `WHERE` (restrição)

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE td2.data = '2017-02-10'
```

Answer (score 6):

Sim você pode, porém é o caso de utilizá-lo apenas quando a chave é composta. A restrição de resultados deve ser feita no `WHERE`.

Comment: O que seria uma chave composta?

Comment: [Quando é recomendado o uso de chave primária composta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15883/quando-%C3%A9-recomendado-o-uso-de-chave-prim%C3%A1ria-composta)